# HDF5ExtError using Dask multiprocesses

Tags: python, dask, hdf5, h5py

I am calculating mean using Dask on a data which I downloaded from [here](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Transportation/2018-Yellow-Taxi-Trip-Data/t29m-gskq). As I am getting hands-on, on Dask, I converted the csv file into hdf5.

I am using the configuration: Dask 2.19 version, Python 3.8, Pandas 1.0.5 and h5py 2.10.0.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df_csv = dd.read_csv("2018_Yellow_Taxi_Trip_Data.csv", dtype={'DOLocationID': 'float64',
       'PULocationID': 'float64',
       'RatecodeID': 'float64',
       'passenger_count': 'float64',
       'payment_type': 'float64'})

# converting it to hdf5 format
df_csv.to_hdf(path_or_buf="2018_Yellow_Taxi_Trip_Data.h5", key="taxi_data",
              format="table")
```

Reading hdf5 using dask

```
filename = "2018_Yellow_Taxi_Trip_Data.h5"
temp_trip_data = dd.read_hdf(pattern=filename, key="taxi_data")

#getting passenger count from temp_trip_data
time_series = temp_trip_data["passenger_count"]
```

#### computing mean using default attributes

```
print(time_series.mean().compute())
1.5731398237126735
```

#### Changing configuration to run it on multiple processes

```
da.config.set(scheduler='processes')
```

#### getting mean after setting schedule to processes

```
print(time_series.mean().compute())
```

## Giving me an error : HDF5ExtError

Further details about the error

```
HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5F.c", line 509, in H5Fopen
    unable to open file
  File "H5Fint.c", line 1400, in H5F__open
    unable to open file
  File "H5Fint.c", line 1615, in H5F_open
    unable to lock the file
  File "H5FD.c", line 1640, in H5FD_lock
    driver lock request failed
  File "H5FDsec2.c", line 941, in H5FD_sec2_lock
    unable to lock file, errno = 11, error message = 'Resource temporarily unavailable'

End of HDF5 error back trace

Unable to open/create file '2018_Yellow_Taxi_Trip_Data.h5'
```

This seems to be a very strange behaviour. Any idea why this is happening ? What is wrong with Dask?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to not use HDF5, but instead switch to a more modern format, like Parquet.